# How to stop a thread without using the stop Method?

Tags: java, multithreading

In the Following Java Program I am storing 3 threads in a HashMap, I have created 3 objects of Th class which is extended from Class Thread (I have tried by Implementing the Runnable but it is also not working!), I want to stop the t2 after 3sec by assigning null value I am not able to stop it , I dont want to use the stop() Method as it is deprecated and it only works if I start the threads using start method while it does not work if I start the threads using the execute method of ExecutorService

```
public class TestingThreads {

    static HashMap<String, Thread> trds = new HashMap<>();

    static Th t1 = new Th("Th1");
    static Th t2 = new Th("Th2");
    static Th t3 = new Th("Th3");

    public TestingThreads() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long ct = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        trds.put("t1", t1);
        trds.put("t2", t2);
        trds.put("t3", t3);
        executor.execute(t1);
        executor.execute(t2);
        executor.execute(t3);
        executor.shutdown();
        new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if (ct + 3000 < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                        trds.put("t2", null);
                        trds.remove("t2");
                        System.out.println("Size = " + trds.size());
  //I dont wanna use the stop() method as is it deprecated and it only works when I use start method to run the Thread while it is not working with execute() method of class ExecutorService 
                        // t2.stop();
                        t2 = null;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }.start();
    }
}

class Th extends Thread {

    String name;
    Random rm = new Random();

    public Th(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
            int i = rm.nextInt(500);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
            System.out.println(name + " " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to implement a thread interruption mechanism. Setting a value in a `HashMap` to `null` does absolutely nothing to a thread.

Comment: (Also, there's no point for your class to extend `Thread`, if you are submitting instances of it to an `ExecutorService` as `Runnable`s.)

Comment: But it also not working if I implement the Runnable

Comment: That's why I had it in `()`. It's just a recommendation.

Comment: Thank you Dear and if you have some more useful stuff please share with me :)

Comment: 1 - instead of `while(true)` use `while(!this.isInterrupted())` (inside the run method in your class Th). 2 - instead of `t2.stop()` use `t2.interrupt()`. As @SotiriosDelimanolis said, removing your Th object from the map does nothing to it

Comment: thank you @morgano I replaced while(true) with while(!this.isInterrupted()), but it is still not working :)

Comment: When your thread gets interrupted it will throw that InterruptedException.  Have that catch clause return or set a flag that you use in the loop and then interrupt() will work.  The problem is that sleep() notices the interrupted flag then clears the flag before it throws the exception.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example of one thread..
Create a static volatile boolean flag.

```
static volatile boolean RUN_THREAD_FLAG= true;
Thread yourThread= new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            // you can add your other conditions inside while condition
            // and AND it with the FLAG
            //while(RUN_THREAD_FLAG && yourCondition)
            while(RUN_THREAD_FLAG){ 
                sleep(SLEEP_TIME); //OR your task
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
};
yourThread.start();
```

when ever you want to stop the thread, just set **RUN_THREAD_FLAG= false**

PS: You should always end the thread properly as long as possible using some FLAG or other methods. Don't use any interrupt method as far as you can.

Comment: make that flag volatile, please.  Without it it's not guaranteed that another thread will ever pick it up (if the value is in a cpu cache, for instance)

Comment: There is already such a volatile flag - the thread's interruption flag! You can simple use that instead of introducing a new one!

Comment: -1. I downvoted this because it provides bad advice and misses the point where the OP wants to run tasks using the executorservice and doesn't get why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting your code, can't even stop `t2` using `stop` because `t2` is never started, it is executed by `executor`. To stop `t2` you need to run `t2` directly: (changes done to your last edited code: set the interrupt flag = true if case the thread was interrupted in `sleep`, and executing `t2.start()` instead of `executor.execute(t2)`)

```
public class TestingThreads {

    static HashMap<String, Thread> trds = new HashMap<>();

    static Th t1 = new Th("Th1");
    static Th t2 = new Th("Th2");
    static Th t3 = new Th("Th3");

    public TestingThreads() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long ct = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        trds.put("t1", t2);
        trds.put("t2", t2);
        trds.put("t3", t3);
        executor.execute(t1);
        /*executor.execute(t2);*/ t2.start();
        executor.execute(t3);
        executor.shutdown();
        new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if (ct + 3000 < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                        trds.put("t2", null);
                        trds.remove("t2");
                        System.out.println("Size = " + trds.size());
                        // t2.stop();
                        t2.interrupt();
                        t2 = null;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }.start();
    }
}

class Th extends Thread {

    String name;
    Random rm = new Random();

    public Th(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
            int i = rm.nextInt(500);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                this.interrupt(); // this line was also added
                // or better use "return" as suggested by Bill K
            }
            System.out.println(name + " " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try similar solution as below:-

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

public class TestingThreads {

```
static Th t1 = new Th("Th1");
static Th t2 = new Th("Th2");
static Th t3 = new Th("Th3");

public TestingThreads() {

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
}
```

}
class Th extends Thread {

```
String name;
Random rm = new Random();

public Th(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@Override
public void run() {

    final long ct = System.currentTimeMillis()+3000;
    Thread t= Thread.currentThread();
    System.out.println("Running Thread is :-"+t.getName()+"  "+System.currentTimeMillis());
    while (true) {
        if (ct < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            try{
                System.out.println("Running Thread is :-"+t.getName()+"  "+System.currentTimeMillis());
                t.interrupt();
                break;
            }
            catch(Exception ie)
            {
                System.out.println(t.getName()+" closed");
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your change to use t2.interrupt will work, but you need to change the threads to look like this:  (Note the return statement).

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
        int i = rm.nextInt(500);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(name + " " + i);
    }
}
```

When the sleep method is interrupted it throws the InterruptedException but clears the flag before it does so.  You have to do something inside the exception to make it work.  Another way is:

```
boolean running=true;
@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        int i = rm.nextInt(500);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            running=false;
        }
        System.out.println(name + " " + i);
    }
}
```

Note that since running is only accessed from one thread now it doesn't have to be volatile.

Comment: I think it's in general a bad idea to stop the whole thread only because the sleep was interrupted. IMHO It depends on the logic inside the thread if this is a valid case. In the case of the requestor the solution from @kaze should be prefered.

Comment: @kaze I was wondering about that--do you have any support for that statement?  Mostly I was wondering if an interrupt always worked.  I believe the problem would be if you were doing something else (like listening to a socket) IT might throw the interrupted exception and clear the flag and you wouldn't get it in your sleep statement--but I couldn't come up with a really good reason not to clear the flag in the catch.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, do NOT extend `Thread` for implementing tasks (= piece of work)! I think you've misunderstood the executor framework. It already takes care of the `Threads`, you do not have to create one by yourself! What you want to do is to implement tasks (= implement `Runnable`)  that get executed by an `Executor`.

**Second**, your tasks should be sensitive to interruption, i.e. interrupting the executing thread by calling `interrupt()` should cause your task to finish its work:

```
public class Task implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                int i = rm.nextInt(500);
                Thread.sleep(i);
                System.out.println(name + " " + i);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // restore interruption flag
            Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we can use an infinite loop here as `Thread.sleep` will throw an `InterruptedException` that will exit the loop as soon as the executing `Thread` gets interrupted. (Otherwise we'd have to check the interruption flag by calling `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted` by ourselves).

**Third**, use a `ScheduledExecutorService` for both, execution of your tasks and cancelling:

```
ScheduledExecutorService exectuor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
Future<?> t1f = executor.execute(new Task());
Future<?> t2f = executor.execute(new Task());
Future<?> t3f = executor.execute(new Task());

// now we can cancel tasks individually after a certain amount of time:
executor.schedule(() -> t2f.cancel(true), 3, TimeUnit.SECOND);
```

The last line of code uses lambda expressions available since Java 8. If you don't want to use them or cannot use them for some reason, use a normal `Runnable` again:

```
executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
    public void run() { t2f.cancel(true); }
}, 3, TimeUnit.SECOND);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using a boolean variable:

package com.Exception.Demos;

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    boolean continueThread=true;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int i=0;
        while(true){
            if(continueThread){
                try{
                    System.out.println(i++);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("press enter to stop "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }catch(InterruptedException exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"Ended");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
package com.Exception.Demos;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TerminatingAThread {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    MyRunnable myRunnable=new MyRunnable();
    Thread thread=new Thread(myRunnable,"Thread1");
    thread.start();
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"thread waiting for user to press enter");
    System.in.read();
    myRunnable.continueThread=false;
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"thread ended");
}
}
```

Comment: Adding an explanation how this code answers the question will help future visitors.

Comment: thanks for comment :). the above program was written for a thread to stop when a user hit enter button.

Answer (score 0):

Two main lessons here:

- Don't extend Thread, it just creates opportunities for confusion. (Even if you don't use executors, separating the logic to be executed from the means of executing the task improves clarity.)
- Thread interruption is how tasks get canceled and how executors get shut down in java.util.concurrent, you must understand it in order to use executors effectively.

Now for details:

Thread implements Runnable. When you create instances of Th extending Thread and pass them into the ExecutorService, the executor doesn't run the task on the passed-in thread. It just knows you gave it a Runnable, and it proceeds to execute that Runnable on one of its worker threads.

That is why you're not seeing the interrupt flag get set when you use the ExecutorService. It also explains why it works when you start your own threads. You're looking for the interruption with

```
this.isInterrupted()
```

where `this` is the thread you passed in, but it's the pool's worker thread, not the Th instance, that gets interrupt called on it. Change your check to

```
Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()
```

You should also set the interrupt flag when you catch an InterruptedException. When the sleep method throws InterruptedException it clears the flag (so in the next while loop iteration isInterrupted returns false). Like above, you should call interrupt on the current thread, not on `this`.

The thread waiting for the executor to finish is unneeded (and the busy waiting it's doing is not good), you can call awaitTermination instead.

Also using shutdown doesn't work because these tasks never quit on their own, they have to be interrupted. shutdown politely waits for current tasks to finish, which will never happen; you need shutdownNow in order to interrupt the tasks.

Here is a simpler program to do the same thing, it submits 3 tasks and lets them execute for 3 seconds before shutting down. Notice all the things I don't have to do, I don't have to squirrel the tasks away in a hashmap and I don't need a watchdog thread to wait for the executor to terminate.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class TestThreads {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        executor.execute(new Th("t1"));
        executor.execute(new Th("t2"));
        executor.execute(new Th("t3"));
        Thread.sleep(3000L);
        executor.shutdownNow();
        executor.awaitTermination(10000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println("executor terminated=" + executor.isTerminated());
    }
}

class Th implements Runnable {

    String name;
    Random rm = new Random();

    public Th(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            int i = rm.nextInt(500);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(i); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            System.out.println(name + " " + i);
        }
    }
}
```